# Excel VBA Match to find first row number matching multiple criteria contained in array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the first row number that matches two criteria located in two columns and in an array in my code.

ex:

```
market = Array("market1", "market2", "market3"...)
report = Array("report1", "report2", "Report3"...)

rownumber = Application.Match(Range("B:B" & "L:L"), market(i) & report(z))
ws2.Range("N2").Value = rownumber
```

is there a way to do this? let me know if you need anything else

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to have `Application.Match` nested inside the other.

Comment: @ShaiRado as MATCH returns a long, how would nesting one inside the other work?  I am not following the logic, so I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array formula and as such it cannot be done with Application.Match.  You can use Evaluate.

```
market = Array("market1", "market2", "market3"...)
report = Array("report1", "report2", "Report3"...)
Dim rownumber As Variant
rownumber = ws2.Evaluate("IFERROR(Match(""" & market(0) & report(0) & """,B:B & L:L, 0),""Not Found"")")
ws2.Range("N2").Value = rownumber
```

If the search range is not found on `ws2` change the `ws2` in front of `.Evaluate` to the worksheet on which the data is found.

***But when using array formulas one should not use full column references, try to find the extent of the data and reference just those cells.***

Comment: Thanks Scott, however when running that code I am returning a #value - please advise

Comment: @messi1335 see edit.  I had `()` in the wrong place.